# How to dynamicly apply variable modifiers in Smarty 2.x

Tags: php, dynamic, smarty, ondemand, modifiers

I can't find the solution of applying modifiers dynamicly in Smarty.

Template - I would like to work this way (example)

```
{$myVariable|$modifiers}
```

Php script

```
$smarty->assign('myVariable', "brumla brumla na drum drum drum");
$smarty->assign('modifiers', "truncate:30|trim");
```

Or I would like to apply modifiers in php - is there any method for parsing and applying modifiers in php?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Smarty modifier is really PHP function called **smarty_modifier_*$name***(). This function can be called as any other.

So in that example code you'd just do:

```
<?php
$myVariable = "brumla brumla na drum drum drum";
$myVariable = smarty_modifier_truncate($myVariable, 30);
$myVariable = smarty_modifier_trim($myVariable);
$smarty->assign('myVariable', $myVariable);
```

Of course you can use [call_user_func()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) to make it more dynamic.

Comment: And what about modifier date_format if I haven't instance of Smarty. This modifier calls smarty object...